# I'm trying to add some rows to an HTML table, but it's failing

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

***Note:*** this is meant to be a community wiki post

The following code using simple dom methods fails to add rows to the table. What's the issue?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Test</title>
<script>
function addRow() {
    var mytable = document.getElementById('mytable');

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    var text = document.createTextNode('This is a row');

    cell.appendChild(text);
    row.appendChild(cell);
    mytable.appendChild(row);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">

<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <td>This is a row</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="addRow()" value="Add A Row"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a more in-depth example for this:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19561902/2536357

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue at hand here is that the `<table>` element's correct structure is not present. When dealing with tables, the basic structure is:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Heading for the table</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>A row of data</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The logic is that when dealing with tables, you want to keep the labels of the columns, and the actual data separate. Because most browsers fill in the `<tbody>` as part of the process of fixing broken HTML, few people realize this. When the browser sees you adding a `<tr>`, it doesn't know if you're trying to add it to the `<thead>` or the `<tbody>`, so it fails.

The following shows the correct method for adding the rows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Test</title>
<script>
function addRow() {
    var mytbody = document.getElementById('mytbody');

    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    var text = document.createTextNode('This is a row');

    cell.appendChild(text);
    row.appendChild(cell);
    mytbody.appendChild(row);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">

<table id="mytable">
<tbody id="mytbody">
<tr>
    <td>This is a row</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="addRow()" value="Add A Row"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 Guilty as charged.  I frankly almost never bother with thead & tbody tags in a table.  Now I will. :-)

Comment: It's important to point out that `tbody` and `thead` are actually only required in strict XHTML, and that basically every browser supports [`insertCell` and `insertRow`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#tables)

Answer (score -1):

Any additional row needs to be added then take the first child of tableID and then use appendChild() method:

```
var tbl=document.getElementById("tbl");
var row=document.createElement("tr");
var cel=document.createElement("td");
cel.innerHTML='sometext';
row.appendChild(cel);
tbl.children[0].appendChild(row);
```